# heroku django Amazon S3. video recording and playing

Tags: django, heroku, amazon-s3, video-streaming, webcam

everybody!

I have django app running on heroku server. I attached amazon S3 storage to it.
I want to allow users record webcam videos, then upload them (to S3 ultimately) and then other users to play them.

What is the easiest way to do that?
I have alteady spent more than 20 hours on research around this topic but I still have no idea.
People usualy uses some streaming servers like RED5 + flash players + something + something.. But it seems to be very compicated and is not appropriate for heroku as I understood...

I would appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0):

The solution that most people go with is to use a flash applet to record into memory, and then bulk upload it at the end. [Nimbb](http://nimbb.com/Help/Api.aspx) seems to be the one most people go with.

Alternatively, Youtube has a pretty neat API for doing recording and uploading to their servers entirely from within your site.

> The YouTube Upload Widget lets your website's visitors perform both webcam and file uploads to YouTube. The support for webcam uploads sets the upload widget apart from the other uploading options that the YouTube API supports. The widget uses HTML5's postMessage support to send messages back to your website regarding videos uploaded via the widget.

Comment: Unfortanutaly Nimbb is too expensive for me. Whereas youtube API for recording videos requires EACH user to have their own youtube chanel. Which is obviously not that great. I recently found http://www.scriptcam.com - they seem to solve my problems. I will write back when try them out.

Comment: well hey, anyone with a youtube account has a channel. And most people with a google account now have a youtube account. So what's the real problem?